# Scale text without scaling shape

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I figured out the only way to make a shape larger is by scaling it, not by setting a width and height. So I scaled the shape like this:

```
toObject: function() {
            return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper("toObject"), {
                objectSize: this.objectSize,
                scaleX: this.scaleX,
                scaleY: this.scaleY,
                labelColor: this.labelColor,
                hasRotatingPoint: this.hasRotatingPoint,
                hasControls: this.hasControls,
                evented: this.evented,
                hoverCursor: this.hoverCursor,
                _controlsVisibility: this._controlsVisibility
            });
        },
```

but the `ctx.fillText` also scales with it. That is *not* what I want. The text needs to stay the same. So i did the following:

```
_render: function(ctx) {
            this.callSuper("_render", ctx);
            ctx.font = "12px Helvetica";
            ctx.fillStyle = this.labelColor;
            ctx.scale(1 / this.scaleX, 1 / this.scaleY);
            ctx.fillText(
                this.objectSize,
                 -this.objectSize.split('x')[0] / 2 + 10, 
                 -this.objectSize.split('x')[1] / 2 - 5
            );
        }
```

Now the issue is that at some shape sizes (for example 200x200) the object also scales with it. When I remove the `ctx.scale(1 / this.scaleX, 1 / this.scaleY)` the object has the right size, except then the text is also scaled up.

How can I scale the shape without scaling the text or visa versa.